# Deixar o fundo "torto" - WORDPRESS

Tags: wordpress

Como deixar o fundo ondulado, como no site dessa imagem a seguir?

[image: _Landing Page_ com desenho ondulado no fundo]

Answer (score 1):

Basta você salvar uma imagem em PNG de com a cor da div, e colocá-la abaixo da mesma.

Ou você pode utilizar o código.

```css
.box2 {
    background-color: #FF895B;
    position: relative;
    height: 500px;
}
.box2:after {
    background: inherit;
    bottom: 0;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 50%;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    transform: skewY(1.5deg);
    transform-origin: 0%;
}
```

```html
<!-- Box 2 -->
<div class="box2">
</div>
```